# Project Euler #5, Python

Tags: python

I started to solve projecteuler problems and so far i find things so difficult. For #5, the problem is:
2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?
I wrote a code for this problem in Python 3, however it takes forever to run, i can't get an answer back. What is causing it to be so slow?
I know the code is really messy and probably full of mistakes and maybe even stupid, but i have been learning python for a month now so i am pretty new to this. Please help me I'm gonna go crazy

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x %2 == 0 and x != 2:
        return False
    elif x == 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    for i in range(3,x,2):
        if x % i == 0 and x != i:
            return False
    return True

def problem(x):
    primes = []
    nonprimes = []
    factors = []
    for i in list(filter(is_prime,range(1,x+1))):
        primes.append(i)
        factors.append((i,1))
    for y in range(1,x+1):
        if y not in primes:
            nonprimes.append(y)
    primes.sort()
    nonprimes.sort()
    for z in nonprimes:
        for t in primes:
            factor = 0
            while z % t == 0:
                factor +=1
            if factor:
                if (t,1) in factors:
                    factors.remove((t,1))
                factors.append((t,factor))
    answer = 1
    for (m,n) in factors:
        answer *= m**n
    return answer
```

Comment: Please copy in your code as *text*, not an image; this is a requirement of [MCVE]s, and it saves people helping you a lot of work (thereby increasing the number of people willing to help).

Comment: Solutions to Project Euler problems are well documented: https://github.com/nayuki/Project-Euler-solutions

Comment: Sorry for adding pictures instead of code, fixed it, thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to accumulate the least common multiple (LCM) for numbers from 1 to N.

The LCM of A and B is defined as A*B/gcd(A,B) where gcd is the greatest common divisor

So a simple loop like this will run in a short time:

```
from math import gcd

N = 20
result = 1
for m in range(2,N+1):
    result = result*m//gcd(result,m)
```

Or, expressed as a recursive function:

```
def lcm(a,b): return a*b//gcd(a,b)
def nextMultAll(N): return lcm(N,nextMultAll(N-1)) if N-1 else 1

nextMultAll(25) # 26771144400
```